# Rotar contenido de una JLabel en java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo una aplicación la cual consta de un `JPanel`, en ese Panel puedo agregar componentes de tipo `JLabel` los cuales contiene un texto. Necesito que esos `jlabel` se les pueda dar rotación cuando se presione el siguiente botón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado el siguiente método para cambiar su rotación pero no consigo que se repinte el mismo `label`.

```js
label = new JLabel("prueba") {
protected void paintComponent(Graphics grafico) {

Graphics2D graficoNuevo = (Graphics2D) grafico;

AffineTransform at = graficoNuevo.getTransform();

double X = getWidth() / 2.0;
double Y = getHeight() / 2.0;

at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), X, Y);

graficoNuevo.setTransform(at);
super.paintComponent(graficoNuevo);
}
};
```

Este codigo funciona para crear una nueva `label` pero lo que necesito en realidad es que la `label` ya creada anteriormente cambie su rotación del texto que contenga.

Comment: y por qué no usas repaint en el listener del botón que vas a presionar?

Comment: Si pero como le doy rotación a su contenido, el codigo que puse de ejemplo no funciona

Comment: Intenta rotando el gráfico en lugar del affineTransform 
`graficoNuevo.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), X, Y);
graficoNuevo.setTransform(at);`